# onReceive() gets called once and then the app shuts down abnormally

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The onReceive() in my class listens for SMSs and sends an SMS in reply, everything is working fine but once. After sending SMS the app shuts down with the message "Unfortunately, yourApp has stopped". I want it to remain active. I wonder where I'm missing out. Thanks for help!

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String TAG="SMSReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
    SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
    int i;
    Toast.makeText(context,"Intent recieved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i(TAG,"Intent recieved: "+intent.getAction());
    String messageContent="";

             if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                 if (bundle != null) {

                     Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                     final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                     for (i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                         messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                         messageContent=messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                     }
                     if (messages.length > -1 && messageContent.charAt(8)=='#') {
                         Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                         Toast.makeText(context, "Message received from victim: "+messageContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         smsManager.sendTextMessage("+919032687185",null,"Request#",null,null);
                         //Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         /*for(i=0;i<7;i++){
                             MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.fire_engine_siren_could_be_police_ambulance_etc);
                             mediaPlayer.start();
                         }*/
                     }
                     /*else if(messages.length > -1 && messageContent.charAt(6) == '#'){



                         Log.i(TAG, "Location from patrol" + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                         Toast.makeText(context, "Message received from ambulance: "+messageContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }*/
                 }
             }

}
```

}

Comment: And what does LogCat say?

Comment: show the logcat output to see where app is crashing

Comment: Yes, at first call the app logged 2 LogCat messages and at 2nd call it logged only one i. e "Intent received: android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED". It means the onReceive() is called again and then the app crashes

Comment: The logcat messages mention above were of onReceive() method only.

Comment: 02-07 08:50:30.314: W/dalvikvm(20951): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419a5c98)
02-07 08:50:30.314: W/dalvikvm(20951): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
02-07 08:50:30.315: W/System.err(20951): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.androidxambulance.SMSReceiver: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're getting a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` and my guess is the culprit is `messageContent.charAt(8)` because the logcat indicates `length=8; index=8`

Try using [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) instead if finding this #'s location is necessary. Its a bit more flexible and won't throw exceptions at you.

Comment: Yes buddy, StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is stopping the app when the SMS received is of length less than 8 characters.